# How Add TabHost activity which open onclick of button not tab?

Tags: android

I am adding TabHost(it is like iphone) in My application,when click any TabHost Move to other Activity its cool And Tabhost in Botton as usual.But issue is that when I click a button which is on top of Activity Move other Activity in this case TabHost Not Visible on bottom flow is like that

suppose there are 5 tabhost A,B,C,D,E each tabhost have an activity.

case A(click first tabhost):

open Anctivity in that Activity TabHost is present in bottom and there is button on top  of   this activity.

When click on that button open other Activity but in this case there is no tabhost on the bottom of this activity.But need is that there should be  Tabhost anyone suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this one

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablayout-example/

and this

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.